# Finding a maximum weight clique in a weighted graph C# implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

Is there a freely available implementation of finding a maximum weight clique in weighted graph in C#?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: It's not a homework. Just lack of knowledge of algorithms.

Comment: MSDN has a series containing a C# implementation of maximum clique. You might be able to adapt them to weighted maximum. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456397.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547104.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find maximum clique is an NP-hard problem. You can find something useful in [Clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2):

You could read the paper "A fast algorithm for the maximum clique problem", and you will find an effective maximum clique algorithm that proposed in this paper. In addition, a maximum weighted algorithm could be found in "A new algorithm for the maximum weighted clique problem". Here is the Pseudo-Code:

```
1 **FUNCTION CLIQUE(U, size)**
2 if |U| = 0 then
3     if size > max then
4         max ← size
5         New record; save it.
6         found ← true
7     end
8     return
9 end
10 while |U| != ∅ do
11     if size + weight(|U|) <= max then
12         return
13     end
14     i ← min{ j|vj ∈ U}
15     if size + c[i] <= max then
16         return
17     end
18     U ← U ∖ {vi}
19     CLIQUE(U ∩ N(vi); size + weight(vi))
20     if found = true then
21         return
22     end
23 end
24 return
25 **FUNCTION NEW()**
26 max ← 0
27 for i ← n downto 1 do
28     found ← false
29     CLIQUE(Si ∩ N(vi), weight(i))
30     c[i] ← max
31 end
32 return
```

We assume Si represents vertexes that have larger index than i, for example {vi,vi+1,...,vn}. N(vi) means the adjacent vertexes of vi. The global variable *max* marks the maximum size of clique that we find for now, and the global variable *found* marks whether we have found a larger clique. The array c[] record the maximum clique size of Si. *size* records maximum clique size in local recursion。

There are several prune strategies that could avoid useless search, especially, in line 11 and line 15.

You could use the hash table to implement this algorithm.